# What does Cech $1$-cohomology $\check{H}^1(X)$ tell you?

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology

I plan to study this subject in depth, but before that I'd just like to get a broad understanding.

I understand that Cech $0$-cohomology $\check{H} ^0(X)$ counts the number of quasi-components of a space.  How about  $\check{H} ^1(X)$?

Specifically, can you explain these two excerpts:

(1)

If $X$ is the closed topologist sine curve, then

[image]

(2)

[image]

Comment: The short answer is that Cech cohomology is not invariant under weak homotopy equivalence, so it detects some pathologies that singular homology does not. By Whitehead's theorem, this isn't an issue for CW-complexes.